# '=' left operator must be an l-value problem encountered while passing value from a function in visual studio C

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, matrix, pass-by-reference

I'm programming in visual studio C. The program consist tomonitorate monopoly's game and I was wondering about how to passing value of a matrix of struct from a function, but it gaves me error C2106 ('=' left operator must be an l-value).

This is my code in main.c:

```
campo = play(gioca, campo, &sortedPlayers, roundPlayer);
/*gioca and roundPlayer are both an int value
* sortedPlayers is a list of struct
* campo[][] is an matrix of struct (is the field of the game)
*/
```

This is my code in the header file:

```
casa** play(int scelta, casa campo[DIM_CAMPO][DIM_CAMPO], playerlist* players, int idP);
```

And this is my code in the .c file:

```
casa** play(int scelta, casa campo[DIM_CAMPO][DIM_CAMPO], playerlist* players, int idP) {
    int dado1, dado2, isDadoDoppio, idx;
    player player;
    playerlist copiaPlayers = emptylistP(), defPlayers = emptylistP();
    switch (scelta) {
    case 0:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 1:
        srand(time(NULL));
        dado1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        dado2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        printf("\nIl numero uscito e': %d + %d", dado1, dado2);
        if (dado1 == dado2)
            isDadoDoppio = 1;
        else
            isDadoDoppio = 0;

        copiaPlayers = *players;
        while (!emptyP(copiaPlayers)) {
            player = headP(copiaPlayers);

            /* Movimento giocatore */
            if (player.idP = idP) {
                for (idx = 0; idx < dado1 + dado2; idx++) {
                    //printf("\n[%d][%d] --> ", player.x, player.y);
                    if (player.x == 0 && (player.y <= 10 && player.y > 0))
                        player.y += 1;
                    else if (player.x == 10 && (player.y <= 10 && player.y > 0))
                        player.y -= 1;
                    else if (player.y == 0  && (player.x <= 10 && player.x > 0))
                        player.x -= 1;
                    else if (player.y == 10 && (player.x <= 10 && player.x > 0))
                        player.x += 1;
                    //printf("[%d][%d]", player.x, player.y);
                }
                break;
            }
            defPlayers = newPlayer(player, defPlayers);
            campo[player.x][player.y].simbolo = (char)player.idP;
            copiaPlayers = tailP(copiaPlayers);
        }

        break;
    }
    return campo;
}
```

Comment: `case 1: srand(time(NULL));` this is wrong: [`srand()` — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Comment: `if (player.idP = idP) {` hmm... is that what you want? Or should it be `if (player.idP == idP) {`

Comment: yeah is if (player.idP == idP), my bad. but there's still the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
campo = play(gioca, campo, ...
```

I bet that `campo` in the assignment is an array. You can't assign arrays.

Also if you pass the 2D array as parameters you cant return pointer to pointer. Arrays are not pointers!!!

Comment: so how I can pass a 2D array from a function?

Comment: you can only pass the reference (pointer) to an array.